# how to animate a circle

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, paintcomponent

Im in the process of learning GUI in Java. Im making this very simple GUI that literally scales the circle size every 5 milliseconds and then once the width and height reaches a certain number, it scales back down and it keep on doing this process. Ive managed to make the circle appear on the screen but for some weird reason its not scaling.

```
public class circle extends JPanel implements ActionListener {



    Timer tm = new Timer(5, this);

    int XDiameter = 20;
    int YDiameter = 20;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(40, 40, XDiameter, YDiameter);

        tm.start();
    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        SuperSizeCircle();
        repaint();

    }

    public void SuperSizeCircle(){
        while(true){
            XDiameter = XDiameter + 2;
            YDiameter = YDiameter + 2;
            if(XDiameter > 200 && YDiameter > 200){
                XDiameter --;
                YDiameter --;
            }else if(XDiameter < 20 && YDiameter < 20){
            XDiameter ++;
            YDiameter ++;
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Main class:

```
public class main {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle enlarger");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400,400);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    circle co = new circle();
    frame.add(co);

}
```

}

Comment: The Timer repaints the GUI every 5 millis for you. You shouldn't have an infinite loop in `SuperSizeCircle()` (which should be named `superSizeCircle()`).

Comment: Add `co`, _then_ `setVisible()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `while(true)` is never good in `Swing` animation. Throw it out the window and say goodbye to it forever. Take that out of your method. You don't need it. The timer takes care of the *"looping"*
2. Don't start the `Timer` in the `paintComponent` method. Do it in the constructor.
3. You should run your Swing apps on the Event Dispatch Thread by wrapping your code in a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater..`. See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details.
4. You should be setting the frame visible *after* adding all component.
5. You `if` statements in your `SuperSizeCircle()` mess with each other if you look at the logic. That's why you need the keep adding. That doesn't look right to me. Instead us a flag (boolean) to determine whether it should grow or shrink

   ```
   boolean grow = true;

   public void SuperSizeCircle() {

       if (XDiameter >= 200) {
           grow = false;
       }
       if (XDiameter <= 20) {
           grow = true;
       }

       if (grow) {
           XDiameter += 2;
           YDiameter += 2;
       } else {
           XDiameter -= 2;
           YDiameter -= 2;
       }
   }
   ```

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CirclePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    Timer tm = new Timer(15, this);

    boolean grow = true;

    int XDiameter = 20;
    int YDiameter = 20;

    public CirclePanel() {
        tm.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(50, 50, XDiameter, YDiameter);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        SuperSizeCircle();
        repaint();

    }

    public void SuperSizeCircle() {

        if (XDiameter >= 200) {
            grow = false;
        }
        if (XDiameter <= 20) {
            grow = true;
        }

        if (grow) {
            XDiameter += 3;
            YDiameter += 3;
        } else {
            XDiameter -= 3;
            YDiameter -= 3;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Circle enlarger");
                CirclePanel co = new CirclePanel();
                frame.add(co);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks. Hadn't thought of writing the superSizeCircle method that way. I have a couple of questions:
How does the program know to paint a circle? Im not explicitly calling the paintComponent method..
Why is it bad to keep an infinite loop going on in a GUI? Is it because its a resource hog?
Why is the logic in my loop that increases/decreases the scale of the circle bad? Im trying to think like a robot and honestly cant find a 'loophole' that will not make me follow those sets of commands.

Anyways, thanks for the help. It works perfectly :D

Comment: Every `JComponent` implicitly calls it own `paintComponent` method. What you are doing is overriding the `default` functionality of `JPanel`s `paintComponent` method. Its bad to keep an infinite loop because you will block the program from performing other functions. In your case, the look will never exit the method. I'm not sure about your logic, it just looked wrong to me. Look at it. It'll grow, but once it gets to 200 it will still grow because your increasing by two and decreaing by 1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) based solution, just for variation.

[image: small] [image: big]

```
import javafx.animation.ScaleTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class CircleScaler extends Application {

    private static final double MIN_RADIUS = 10;
    private static final double MAX_RADIUS = 100;
    private static final double PANE_SIZE  = 2 * (MIN_RADIUS + MAX_RADIUS);
    private static final double SCALE_FACTOR = MAX_RADIUS / MIN_RADIUS;
    private static final Duration SCALE_DURATION = Duration.seconds(3);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final Circle circle = new Circle(MIN_RADIUS, Color.CRIMSON);

        final StackPane root = new StackPane(circle);
        root.setPrefSize(PANE_SIZE, PANE_SIZE);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, Color.PALETURQUOISE));
        stage.show();

        animateCircle(circle);
    }

    private void animateCircle(Circle circle) {
        ScaleTransition scaler = new ScaleTransition(
                SCALE_DURATION,
                circle
        );
        scaler.setFromX(1);
        scaler.setToX(SCALE_FACTOR);
        scaler.setFromY(1);
        scaler.setToY(SCALE_FACTOR);

        scaler.setAutoReverse(true);
        scaler.setCycleCount(ScaleTransition.INDEFINITE);
        scaler.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

For more sophisticated animated circles in JavaFX, see [james-d's animation of 300 balls](https://gist.github.com/james-d/8327842).